# Arraybuffer to Base64 for large videos crashing in ChromeApp

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-os

I am creating a Chrome Application and I'm trying to convert a video I get back as a arraybuffer from a xmlHttpRequest to Base64 so I am able to store it in chrome.storage (as chrome.storage does not support storing blobs or straight up arraybuffers).

I am using this function to encode/convert

```
this.arrayBufferToBase64 = function ( buffer, type ) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
        }
        if (type == "video"){
            return 'data:video/webm;base64,' + window.btoa( binary );
        }
        else{
            return 'data:image/png;base64,' + window.btoa( binary )
        }
    }
```

Videos that are 20MB's work just fine, but it seems video's that are over 200MB just crash the application.

So couple of questions with this:

Is there a better way to convert from arraybuffer to base64?

Is there a way to storge a non-serialize-able object (example blob) into chrome.storage?

Any other suggestions welcome

Comment: Have you tried creating `data URI` in increments?

Comment: I don't think so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could set `responseType` to `"blob"`, use `FileReader()` , `.readAsDataURL()` to read returned `Blob` from request as a `data URI`

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. It's definitely an issue with the Data URI as if I take that out and just to a blob to objectURL it works just fine. Frustrating that I cannot store a blob into chrome.storage as that exactly what I need right now.

Comment: Try determining storage quota. A 200MB `data URI` is probably a lengthy string

Comment: It's a Chrome Application and I've given it the unlimitedstorage permission. Plus even if I don't try to store it in storage it still crashes. It's something to do with the actually creating of the DataURI from such a large (250MB+) .mp4.

Comment: How long do you want to store `data URI`?

Comment: Pretty Permanent. I need it to save data and incase of network loss.

Comment: Try using `requestFileSystem`

Comment: Yah, was hoping to avoid having a user have to choose default folders for storage but it seems it might be the only way. I'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "choose default folders"?

Comment: yah with Chrome Apps I believe it has to prompt the user to choose a default folder to access the filesystem: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: Believe that you can use `window.requestFileSystem`, which is not `chrome.fileSystem`, without prompting user at chrome app. Modified https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access to do the same

Comment: You can substitute `window.requestFileSystem` for `chrome.fileSystem` and by-pass button click to save portions. Will require several modifications, though possible.

Comment: oh wow, ok. I'll look at that example and see what I can do. Thanks!